# Setting `InitialDir` property of `TSelectDirectoryDialog` mutiple times

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I'm trying to use the `InitialDir` property of [`TSelectDirectoryDialog`](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/TSelectDirectoryDialog):

```
procedure selectfolder;
begin
SelectDirectoryDialog1.InitialDir := strPath;
If SelectDirectoryDialog1.Execute then begin
   Edit1.Text := SelectDirectoryDialog1.FileName; 
   end;
end;
```

The first time (with strPath=X) it works fine, the second time I'm using this procedure (with strPath=Y) it doesn't use the new path (Y), but the one I selected previously.

Do I have to call a method, something like `SelectDirectoryDialog1."reinitiate"` before I set the InitialDir property a second time? Another idea would be to use a different property then InitialDir, but I don't know which one would do the job. Unfortunately the [doc page](http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/dialogs/tselectdirectorydialog.html) for `TSelectDirectoryDialog` is currently down, so I don't have a description for the available methods/properties for `TSelectDirectoryDialog` and the ones I tested to solve my problem.

I got it to work if I create the TSelectDirectoryDialog class instance manually and don't use the one from the Component Palette to create it "on the form". Then I just destroy the instance and create a new one.

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var SelectDirectoryDialogManual : TSelectDirectoryDialog;
begin

SelectDirectoryDialogManual := TSelectDirectoryDialog.Create(nil);
SelectDirectoryDialogManual.InitialDir := 'C:\Windows';
if SelectDirectoryDialogManual.Execute then ShowMessage(SelectDirectoryDialogManual.FileName);
SelectDirectoryDialogManual.Free;
end;
```

But how do I do that when I created SelectDirectoryDialog1 using the component Component Palette?

Comment: "Unfortunately the doc page ..."  Have you tried looking at the source?

Comment: @MartynA what do you mean?

Comment: I mean the source code.

Comment: @MartynA sorry, I have no clue what you mean, which source code and how is it suppose to help me?

Comment: I mean. the source code of TSelectDirectoryDialog which you should find in the Dialogs.Pas unit of your Lazarus install.  Just select `Dialogs` in your form's Uses list then press [Enter} and it should open automatically.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I found the source code (doesn't work by pressing enter, but it shows you the filepath), I'm probably just not seeing the obvious but I'm still not know how this is suppose to help me?!

Comment: Well, if you can't "sight-read" the source ofTWin32WSSelectDirectoryDialog, put a breakpoint on its first line and single-step it.

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly, I looked up the source code in "C:\ProgramFiles\lazarus\lcl\dialogs.pp". Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was thinking of Delphi (which uses the  .Pas extension for source code units).

Comment: ok, i found it and I found the part refering to TSelectDirectoryDialog under the section { TSelectDirectoryDialog }. Still don't how this is supposed to help me (beside the point the resetting the FileName property was a viable solution - but I'm still interested in your approach since I learned quite a few new things).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By saving and restoring the value of InitialDir before each invocation of Execute, or doing what @Sertac says in a comment, which works but is less "self-documenting" imo, ymmv.

The code below works fine for me.  `edInitialDir` is a `TEdit` which saves the most recent directory selected using `SelectDirectoryDialog1`, which is then used for the next invocation.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SelectDirectoryDialog1.InitialDir := edInitialDir.Text;

  if SelectDirectoryDialog1.Execute then
    Caption := 'executed'
  else
    Caption := 'not executed';

  edInitialDir.Text := SelectDirectoryDialog1.FileName;
end;
```

Note:  All properties of `SelectDirectoryDialog1` are the defaults for an instance freshly added from the Component Palette.

Regarding your comment, TSelectDirectoryDialog.Execute calls TWin32WSSelectDirectoryDialog.CreateHandle (see Dialogs.Pas, line 1219).  The initial part of this is as follows:

```
class function TWin32WSSelectDirectoryDialog.CreateHandle(const ACommonDialog: TCommonDialog): THandle;
var
  Options : TOpenOptions;
  InitialDir : string;
  Buffer : PChar;
  bi : TBrowseInfo;
  iidl : PItemIDList;
  biw : TBROWSEINFOW;
  Bufferw : PWideChar absolute Buffer;
  InitialDirW: widestring;
  Title: widestring;
  DirName: string;
begin
  DirName := '';
  InitialDir := TSelectDirectoryDialog(ACommonDialog).FileName;
  Options := TSelectDirectoryDialog(ACommonDialog).Options;

  if length(InitialDir)=0 then
    InitialDir := TSelectDirectoryDialog(ACommonDialog).InitialDir;
  if length(InitialDir)>0 then begin
    // remove the \ at the end.                                                                      
    if Copy(InitialDir,length(InitialDir),1)=PathDelim then
      InitialDir := copy(InitialDir,1, length(InitialDir)-1);
    // if it is a rootdirectory, then the InitialDir must have a \ at the end.
    if Copy(InitialDir,length(InitialDir),1)=DriveDelim then
      InitialDir := InitialDir + PathDelim;
  end;
```

From this you can see that it initially attempts to derive the value of InitialDir from the FileName property and only if that results in an empty string does it attempt to use the stored value of the InitialDir property.  This is why the dialog uses the previously-selected directory the next time Execute is invoked, which is exactly what you should be expecting, even if you do not like it.  The only way to re-use the initial value of IntialDir from second and subsequent invocations is to restore it before each one.

Comment: Sorry, your assumption " it should always start with the same preselected directory" is wrong.  The clue is in the property name `TSelectDirectoryDialog.**InitialDir**`.  It means, the directory which will be used on the **first** invocation of `TSelectDirectoryDialog.Execute`, not the one which will be used in subsequent invocations.

Comment: See the update to my answer.  You are stuck with the behaviour unless you do something like my answer!

Comment: All it takes is to reset the file name, e.g. SelectDirectoryDialog1.FileName := '';

Comment: It's still necessary to set the initialdir, I probably didn't understand what is required,

Comment: @SertacAkyuz reseting the FileName does the trick...  the problem was, once the FileName is set, the InitialDir is ignored and I wanted the dialogue to always start every subsequent time with the InitialDir preselected. Thanks! Feel free to write it into a new answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Albin - You're welcome. It's written in this answer now in the first sentence, you can accept it.

Comment: @MartynA what do you mean by "but is less self-documenting"

Comment: Well, with my code, you can see at a glance where the value of InitialDir comes from, whereas the effect of settng FileName is not obvious without either knowledge of its side effect or a reminding comment.

Comment: @MartynA well, I wouldn't call it exactly "at a glance" ;) but it was a good explanation anyway, thanks again. One followup question, you talk about "is to restore it before each one"?! Is there another way to "restore it", then the one Sertac Akyuz suggested?

Comment: None that I know of, apart from what @Sertac said and the alternative I put in my answer.  What would be the point of a third way?